# Show userform if A11:A29 or G8 is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I used to have the following code that worked to bring up a user form (calendar)when A11:A29 or G8 was clicked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A11:A29")) Is Nothing Then DatePickerForm.Show
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G8")) Is Nothing Then DatePickerForm.Show
End Sub
```

I wound up having to scrap that user form due to issues with MS MonthView Control 6.0. I moved to a different calendar found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class). The site suggests using double click anywhere on the sheet to show the userform. This works as designed but does so for any cell whereas I would like to limit it to only cells A11:A29 and G8, either by double clicking or clicking once. I tried modifying the code on the page to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ARange As Range
Dim GRange As Range

Set ARange = Range("A11:A29")
Set GRange = Range("G8")
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, ARange) Is Nothing Then DatePickerForm.Show
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, GRange) Is Nothing Then DatePickerForm.Show
End Sub
```

I get run-time error 91, object variable or with block not set. Debugging highlights the "If isdate" line below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If IsDate(Target.Value) Then
    Calendar1.Value = Target.Value
End If

Call MoveToTarget
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `Target` point to? I don't see any variable or value stored in `Target`.

Comment: If this is based on the activecell being selected to bring up the userform, then *ActiveCell.Value* should be listed.

Comment: @DavidG. I'm sorry - I'm still a novice. I'm not familiar with what the target is exactly. I would think it's where the user is clicking, yes? I thought "setting" the ARange and GRange was pointing it to the target? Pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `Target` is `Range` object familiar only inside the specific Worksheet code module it is placed (like a local variable) , oo it's not recognized inside the `DatePickerForm` form module.

Use:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If IsDate(ActiveCell.Value) Then Calendar1.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End If
```

**Also**, there is a more efficient way to see if `Target` falls inside multiple `Range`, use `Union` to merge multiple `Range`s into one `Range`, see code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim UnionRange As Range

Set UnionRange = Application.Union(Range("A11:A29"), Range("G8"))
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, UnionRange) Is Nothing Then DatePickerForm.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Learned something new with the union piece - thanks! The user form now works when any of those cells are clicked but I still get the same error, this time on the sub MoveToTarget() that's called in the code above. The highlighted code in the debugger is with the 3rd line, dLeft = Target.Left...  Public Sub MoveToTarget() Dim dLeft As Double, dTop As Double dLeft = Target.Left - ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Left + ActiveWindow.Left If dLeft > Application.Width - Me.Width Then 'etc... Sorry, couldn't figure out how to better format with comments.

Comment: @Craig this sounds like a great new post for **SO**. As for this post I think I have answered your current questions, and you can mark as "ANSWER". You should open a new post, with the new error you are getting, and we will gladly help